# Getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported: http://javax.xml.XMLContants/property/accessExternalStylesheet

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI for creating excel file. excel file is getting generated. but seeing an exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported:` [http://javax.xml.XMLContants/property/accessExternalStylesheet](https://%60http://javax.xml.XMLContants/property/accessExternalStylesheet) while persisting workbook on memory.

[image: stack trace info]

Java Version: Open JDK 1.8

Please give me some pointer

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask] and provide a [mcve], not just an error message.

Comment: This issue is fixed in POI 5.2.3